# Use OpenSSL primitives in multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, openssl

I'm working on an application that requires some basic encryption functions (AES and SHA). For reasons which aren't germane I must use OpenSSL's implementations of these primitives.

This application is highly concurrent and currently lock-free, so naturally I am worried about having to manually synchronize calls to these functions.

Is OpenSSL natively thread-safe if I am just using these simple calls? What exactly is the behavior of OpenSSL in a multithreaded setting? The [manual](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#PROG1) is ambiguous here and I've found few external discussions.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Related question: Exactly which internal data structures in OpenSSL are shared/global?

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but would it be smart to trust OpenSSL to be thread safe if it is not clearly advertised by them? Think about upgrades on OpenSSL which could break your code.